Finding α-Quantiles of χ2 Distribution for Variance Estimation
I posted this same question yesterday but it got closed because i hadn't met the guidlines for questions, my apologies guys, so i'm going to re-write it better this time.
Exercise 17. Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$ be i.i.d. where $\mu$ is known, but $\sigma^2$ is unknown. Consider the estimate
$$
\tilde{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\mu\right)^2
$$
for the variance.
b) For $\alpha \in(0,1)$, denote the $\alpha$-quantile of $\chi^2(n)$ by $q_n(\alpha)$. Using this notation, find numbers $a_n, b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $P\left(\tilde{\sigma}^2<a_n \sigma^2\right)=2.5 \%$ and $P\left(\tilde{\sigma}^2>b_n \sigma^2\right)=2.5 \%$.
I think I start by recognizing  the fact that the sampling distribution of the estimator follows a chi-square distribution with n degrees of freedom, so i tried to  find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $P\left(\chi^2(n)<a_n\right)=0.025$ and $P\left(\chi^2(n)>\right.$ $\left.b_n\right)=0.025$, respectively. but i'm not given a specific n value so im not sure how I'm meant to do that.
